# Darken hex color won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I got a little codepen where you can choose your favourite color to "personalize" the website... It changes the background color and the title color (maybe more later), but atm it changes the background to the same color as the title, so the title is invisible... I got a little bit of javascript to lighten/darken hex colors, but that doesn't seem to work.
http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/RKKdqy
And i tried to darken every title with class .title.

With the code

```
$('.title').css('color', color);
$('body').css('background', color);
```

i change the titles and the backgrounds color (My function is called 'color', so the ', color' at the end.
With `$('.title').css.color = lightenDarkenColor(color, -20);` i tried to darken the titles color, but there seems to be a mistake there.

Comment: that code doesn't work with `rgb(r, g, b)` colors (which is what jQuery is giving you), only #rrggbb colors ... and in the click event, you aren't using the `lightenDarkenColor` function to change the color of the title - if that's your code in the codepen you want help with, **post it in the question** - that's how SO works

Comment: `$('.title').css.color` - that's not how jQuery css works ... `$('.title').css('color', color);` that **is** how jQuery css works

Comment: `My function is called 'color'` - it seems to be called `lightenDarkenColor` actually

Comment: Yes I know that it is `$('.title').css('color', color);` , but I need to add the lightenDarkenColor function somehow, so every title gets darker. With `$('.title').css('color', color);` it only changes to the selected color.

I got 2 functions. One function is called 'color' and the other one 'lightenDarkenColor' The first mentioned function is to change the background-color and the title color to the selected one and the second one is to darken the title. But darken the title doesnt work.

Comment: `I got 2 functions. One function is called 'color'` - no **function** called color in the link ... perhaps you posted the wrong link ... that's why I suggested you post your code **in the question**

Comment: You can do it like this: var newColor = lightenDarkenColor(color, -20);
  $('.title').css('color', newColor), but that needs to be inside the click function.
And you need to check your lightenDarkenColor function because it does not return correct value.

Comment: Jaromanda X, yes sorry my **variable** is called color. Not a function.

Comment: Zorken17, Thats seems like a good soluttion to me, but when I do that my title just stay in the default grey. As you said probably my lightenDarkenColor function is wrong. Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: I am working on it, hold on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you solved the problem jet, but you can have a look at a working version here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgxdqK)

This is the method i added instead of your lightenDarkenColor()

```
 //@param  {string} rgb     "rgb(26,26,26)""
 //@param  {string} type    "darken" or "lighten"
 //@param  {int} percent
 //@return {string}         returns the altered RGB color 

function alterColor(rgb, type, percent) {
  rgb = rgb.replace('rgb(', '').replace(')', '').split(',');

  var red = $.trim(rgb[0]);
  var green = $.trim(rgb[1]);
  var blue = $.trim(rgb[2]);

  //If rgb is black set it to gray
  if (red == 0 && green == 0 && blue == 0) {
    red = 100;
    green = 100;
    blue = 100;
  }

  if (type === "darken") {
    red = parseInt(red * (100 - percent) / 100, 10);
    green = parseInt(green * (100 - percent) / 100, 10);
    blue = parseInt(blue * (100 - percent) / 100, 10);
  } else {
    red = parseInt(red * (100 + percent) / 100, 10);
    green = parseInt(green * (100 + percent) / 100, 10);
    blue = parseInt(blue * (100 + percent) / 100, 10);
  }

  rgb = 'rgb(' + red + ', ' + green + ', ' + blue + ')';

  return rgb;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! But how do i darken the colors? I wrote `var darkerColor = alterColor(color, 'darken', 100);` and called it with `$('.title').css('color', darkerColor)` but that doesnt seem to work...

Comment: You don't need to make a new variable darkerColor, you need only change the in parameter lighten to daker as described in the comment.

Like this `var newColor = alterColor(color, 'daker', 100);` and maybe change the percentage to something smaller then 100 (100%)

Comment: Ah ok, and if I want to have different types? So like h1 is lighter and h2 is darker. Then i need 2 different variables, dont I?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Ex. `var h1 = alterColor(color, 'daker', 100);`

Comment: Well, the lighter color is working perfectly in yuor codepen. But when I do `var newColor = alterColor(color, 'darken', 100);` the title is just black.

Comment: Then you have some compilation issues in your code. Share your codepen

Comment: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/RKKdqy) I copied your code and changed "lighten" to "darken"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133647/discussion-between-zorken17-and-tobias-glaus).